# Client-side full-text search on array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, full-text-search

I have the following example JavaScript array of objects and need to enable users to search on it using words/phrases, returning the objects:

```
var items = [];
var obj = {
    index: 1,
    content: "This is a sample text to search."
};
items.push(obj);
obj = {
    index: 2,
    content: "Here's another sample text to search."
};
items.push(obj);
```

It's probably efficient to use jQuery's `$.grep` to perform the search, such as this for a single word:

```
var keyword = "Here";
var results = $.grep(items, function (e) { 
    return e.content.indexOf(keyword) != -1; 
});
```

However, how do you search for a phrase in the `content` field of the objects? For example, searching for the phrase `another text` won't work using `indexOf`, because the two words aren't next to each other. What's an efficient way to perform this search in jQuery?

Comment: how about `:contains`?

Comment: Thanks, @GuruprasadRao. Does `:contains` take into account that the phrase words don't have to be consecutive, but can be anywhere in the text?

Comment: Yes!! Check **[this link](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** for more detail

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use vanilla JS if you're stuck. It does use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which won't work in older browsers, but there are polyfills available.

```js
var items = [];

var obj = {
  index: 1,
  content: "This is a sample text to search."
};

items.push(obj);

obj = {
  index: 2,
  content: "Here's another sample text to search."
};

items.push(obj);

function find(items, text) {
  text = text.split(' ');
  return items.filter(item => {
    return text.every(el => {
      return item.content.includes(el);
    });
  });
}

console.log(find(items, 'text')) // both objects
console.log(find(items, 'another')) // object 2
console.log(find(items, 'another text')) // object 2
console.log(find(items, 'is text')) // object 1
```

(Edit: updated to use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), and a slightly shorter arrow function syntax).

Answer (score 1):

if you use [query-js](http://runefs.com/2015/06/04/working-with-data-in-javascript/) you can do this like so

```
var words = phrase.split(' ');
items.where(function(e){
           return words.aggregate(function(state, w){ 
                    return state && e.content.indexOf(w) >= 0;
                  });
},true);
```

if it should just match at least one change the `&&` to `||` and `true` to `false`

Comment: Thanks, @RuneFS. Very nice. The link is asking me to log into a Wordpress blog.

Comment: The link to GitHub is broken: https://github/runefs/query-js. Where can I download the JS library?

Comment: It should be https://github.com/runefs/query-js or you can install by npm install query-js